# Swift theme change not working on UILabel within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiappearance

I am working on providing a light/dark theme option to the users in an iOS app. When I put the theme in app delegate, the app loads fine with the proper theme but when I toggle a switch in settings to change the theme, it doesn't work properly.

The main problem is with UILabel.textColor in UITableViewCell. I tried the below based on what I read online but it doesn't work.

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewCell.self]).textColor = UIColor.red
```

I am using Xcode 9.3. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `UIAppearance` work only the view isn't loaded yet: "*iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back.*" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance?language=objc

Comment: @Larme Yes I understand that. I am removing from view hierarchy and putting it back. But the issue is that the UILabel within UITableViewCell is not taking this UIAppearance setting.

Comment: @pkc456 Do you know the swift version of that. I did see that message and tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Try reloaddata of your tableview.

Comment: @abilal17 That does not solve the problem. The problem is that the appearance() is not taking effect even on initial load. Not sure why.